# Java Memory Out of Heap Space

Tags: optaplanner

I am using a SOLVER to solve an issue in Java using OptaPlanner but after some point of time, i get an exception saying Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space. What does this signify

Comment: Depending on your problem size, set something like `-Xmx1G -server`. If it still goes out of memory, use VisualVM (or JProfiler or YourKit) to find out why (and assert you don't have a memory leak in your code). All OptaPlanner examples run very comfortably with less than 1GB, except for MachineReassignement which requires 2GB for the infamous B datasets (because loading the datasets B10 in memory alone, without creating a Solver, takes up almost 1.5 GB already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JVM**-Java Virtual Machine will limit your execution with some space of memory if you exceed the allocated memory you got to experience this `"JAVA HEAP SPACE"` ERROR.

You can also increase the Heap space by doing this,

```
java -Xms<initial heap size> -Xmx<maximum heap size> CLASS_FILE_TO_EXECUTE

-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
```

Ie

`java -Xmx2g` assign `2 gigabytes` of ram as maximum to your app

But you should see if you don't have a memory leak first.

Comment: I tried using your solution but it says invalid maximum heap size

Comment: the error is Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Comment: -Xmx2g is the command that i used as a vm argument in eclipse

Comment: that 2g is just an example based upon your machine capacity you try with some other available memory size.

Comment: i am having a system with a memory of 4g, i have tried with 512M, 1024M also same issue

Comment: what it says when you try -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m

Comment: @D3X Try just `-Xmx1024m`. Some older JVM's don't accept heap spaces above 1G.

Comment: You said your machine has 4GB RAM then 32 bit OS itself enough only machine with more than 4GB RAM 64 bit is necessary but 64 bit has some improvement you can try.

Answer (score 1):

Btw What is meant above: adjust the -Xmx setting in runExamples.bat or .sh file in: optaplanner-distribution-6.0.1.Final\examples\ (by default it is 512m). What I do to circumvent this problem and getting better results: I monitor the progress by checking MEM usage in Windows Task Manager. When it gets close to the max value I hit the "Terminate solving early" button. Than I click Save As and store a file in the "Solved" folder. Than I kill all OptaPlanner windows and restart it afresh. In "Quick Open" window I click on the file I just saved and hit Solve again. It will lower the number of Soft Constraints violated a bit better till I see the MEM is close to the limit again. I do this a couple of times till I see 2-3 times that I don't get better results. TADA, workaround.